# Access to props in child component mounted

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-props

From what I understand, because the child component is mounted first then the parent component is mounted, when we try to access props in the child component's mounted period, we will get null.

However, I encountered a situation where props are accessed in the child component's mounted period. It was when the parent component's v-model was an array.

This is the parent component example.

```
<example-input
  v-model="arr[i]"
/>
...
<script>
  ...
  data () {
    return {
      arr = ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  }
</script>
```

This is the child component example.

```
export default {
  props: value,
  ...
  mounted () {
    console.log(this.value) <<< results comes in!
  }
}
```

When I run it, each value in arr is printed.
I am quite confused about this finding.

I tried to search for cases similar to mine, but currently, I am in vain. How come props are accessed in the child component's mounted period? Please help me out with this!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am not sure what issue you are facing, but as we are passing prop from data property, It should be available in the child mounted with irresepect to type (string or array).

Live Demo (Here string type is accessing in the child mounted) **:**

```js
Vue.component('child', {
  props: ['childmsg'],
  template: '<h3>{{ childmsg }}</h3>',
  mounted() {
    console.log('child mounted call', this.childmsg);
  }
});

var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  mounted() {
    console.log('parent mounted call');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <child childmsg="This is a child message">
  </child>
</div>
```

Comment: You are right! The props are accessed in mounted period indeed. However, I am still facing the issue where only arrays are accessed in child's mounted period (in my actual project). Seems that it is just not about how vue's parent-child props normally works, but some other reasons... Guess I have to find that out. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 0):

@codingEffort `console.log()` is passed a reference to the object, so the value in the console will update as the object updates. Objects and Arrays are pass by reference in Javascript.
To see it's true value you can coerce it to a string (which is pass by value) in your mounted call,

```
mounted () {
  console.log('value as string:', JSON.stringify(value))
}
```

OR, create a new object and so a new reference,

```
mounted () {
  console.log('value as array:', JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(value)))
}
```

Comment: Sorry but I am still confused. I tried out "JSON.stringify(value)" as you mentioned. What it did was just make the result in string. I still do not get how come when I pass a (1) string value and console log in mounted, the result is null, whereas when I pass an (2) array like the example above, I get the actual result.
When I  tried (1) and (2) with JSON.stringify(value), the results were (1) - "" / (2) - "a"...